# Bash function with arguments

Tags: bash, function, arguments

I know I can write bash scripts like:

```
foo() {
  echo $1;
}
```

but can I define a function that writes:

```
foo(string) {
  echo $string;
}
```

I just can't find my way out of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only available form is the first one; see [the manual for details](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions).

To use named parameters, the traditional technique is to assign them at the start of your function:

```
foo() {
  string=$1
  # ...
  echo "${string}"
}
```